# Write to DB after Controller has been disposed

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

## Situation

We have a controller where users can submit any number of E-Mail addresses to invite other (potential) members as friends. If an address is not found in the database, we send an E-Mail message to that user. Since the user does not has to wait for this process to complete in order to continue working this is done asynchronously.

Sending E-Mails can take a long time if servers respond slowly, are down or overloaded. The E-Mail sender should update the database according to the status received from the E-Mail server, so for example setting the friend request into "Error" state, when a permanent failure occurs, for example if the address does not exists. For this purpose, the E-Mail component implements the function `SendImmediateAsync(From,To,Subject,Content,Callback,UserArg)`. After the message has been delivered (or it failed), the Callback is called with certain arguments about the Delivery state.

When it eventually calls the delegate, the DbContext object has already been disposed (since the controller has been too) and I cannot manually create a new one using `new ApplicationDbContext()` because there is no constructor that accepts a connection string.

## Question

How can I write to the database long after the controller has been disposed? I have not yet figured out how to manually create a `DbContext` object for myself. An object of type `ApplicationDbContext` is passed to the constructor of the Controller and I hoped I could instantiate one for myself, but the Constructor has no arguments I can supply (for example connection string). I want to avoid to manually create an SQL Connection and assemble INSERT statements manually and would prefer to work with the entity model we have already set up.

## Code

The code shows the affected segment only without any error checking for readability.

```
[Authorize]
public class MembersController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public MembersController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Friends()
    {
        MailHandler.SendImmediateAsync(FROM,TO,SUBJECT,CONTENT,
            delegate (Guid G, object any)
            {
                //THIS IS NOT WORKING BECAUSE _context IS DISPOSED
                var ctx = _context;

                Guid Result = (Guid)any; //user supplied argument

                if (G != Guid.Empty)
                {
                    ctx.MailConfirmation.Add(new MailConfirmation()
                    {
                        EntryId = Result,
                        For = EntryFor.FriendRequest,
                        Id = G
                    });

                    if (G == MailHandler.ErrorGuid)
                    {
                        var frq = _context.FriendRequest.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == Result);
                        frq.Status = FriendStatus.Error;
                        ctx.Update(frq);
                    }
                    ctx.SaveChanges();
                }
            }, req.Id);
        //rendering view
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, when you are using EF Core with ASP.NET Core's dependency injection, each DbContext instance is scoped per-request, unless you have specified otherwise in ".AddDbContext". This means you should not attempt to re-use an instance of DbContext after that HTTP request has completed. See https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html#service-lifetimes-and-registration-options

DbContextOptions, on the other hand, are singletons and can be re-used across requests.

If you need to close the HTTP request and perform an action afterwards, you'll need to create a new DbContext scope an manage it's lifetime.

Second of all, you can overload DbContext's base constructor and pass in DbContextOptions directly. See https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext.html

Together, this is what a solution might look like.

```
public class MembersController : Controller
{
    private DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> _options;

    public MembersController(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
    {
        _options = options;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Friends()
    {
        MailHandler.SendImmediateAsync(FROM,TO,SUBJECT,CONTENT, CreateDelegate(_options) req.Id);
    }

    private static Action<Guid, object> CreateDelegate(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
    {
        return (G, any) => 
        {
            using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext(options))
            {
                //do work
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        };
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base (options) { }

    // the rest of your stuff
}
```

This assumes, of course, that your "MailHandler" class is properly using concurrency to run the delegate so it doesn't block the thread processing the HTTP request.

Comment: This sort of worked. Problem is I can't change `ApplicationDbContext` to inherit from DbContext or the site breaks for some reason. I ended up doing this: Create an `AsyncDbContext` which basically has the same content as `ApplicationDbContext` but inherits from `DbContext`. Then I changed the constructor of my membercontroller to: `public MembersController(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options, ApplicationDbContext context)`, because I still can't manually instantiate AppicationDbContext. This way I get both. The context for the request and the options object for async contexts.

Comment: What does your definition of ApplicationDbContext inherit from then?

Comment: ef creates it as `public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`

Comment: Oh. That actually means you are using ASP.NET Identity which is a layer on top of EF Core. See this code here: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/IdentityDbContext.cs

Answer (score 0):

Why not just pass the dbContext as the userArgs to your SendImmediateAsync?  Then the dbContext will not get disposed and can be passed back when you do the callback.  I'm pretty sure that should work.

Comment: I tried and it didn't work. I think Entity framework explicitly disposes it with the controller.

Comment: Wow, that's pretty interesting.  Inside the controller, can you create a new dbContext object that the controller knows nothing about and pass that one in the userArgs?  Perhaps that will work?

Comment: No I can't. As you see, the constructor receives an object of type `ApplicationDbContext`. When I try to create my own using `new ApplicationDbContext()`, it get's created but as soon as you want to read or write from the database, you receive this error: _No database providers are configured. Configure a database provider by overriding OnConfiguring in your DbContext class or in the AddDbContext method when setting up services._ **Note:** ApplicationDbContext is a type created by entity framework itself and only has an empty constructor

Comment: In the notes of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36609339/how-to-use-injected-dbcontext-in-parallel-methods-in-asp-net-core-and-ef7 , it explains the issue you are seeing: the DbContexts in ASP.NET are registered as scoped by default, this means their lifetime is that of the duration of the request.  When the request ends they get disposed.  The proposed solution is to get a DbContext that is registered with the DI container that has a longer lifetime (I.e. app lifetime duration).  Perhaps that will point you in the right direction.