# Save to DB after response was already sent (.NET Core & EF Core)

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a .Net Core 3.1 Web API using Entity Framework Core. It uses HTTP Polling (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/async-request-reply), so one endpoint can be called to begin a process, another endpoint returns the status of the process, and another endpoint returns the result. In short, the first call is going to return quickly but start a process that will finish after that return. When the process finishes, I need to save something to the DB but my dbContext has already been disposed of.

Here's the full detail:

The Controller action is going to ask an injected service to start the process (A Calculation), and then it's going return the endpoint to call to get more information about the process:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<CalculationResource> createNewCalculationRequest([FromBody, BindRequired] CalculationRequestResource calculationRequest)
{
    var calc = _service.newCalculation(calculationRequest.Formats, calculationRequest.ParticipantId, calculationRequest.CaseId, calculationRequest.Input);
    var calcResponse = _mapper.Map<CalculationResource>(calc);
    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(getCalculation), new { calculationId = calc.Id }, calcResponse);
}
```

The service is going to save that Calculation, and then ask a Driver to start it. The driver will synchronously return that the process was started (or not). At this point the response is sent, but when the driver was asked to start the Calculation, it was given a function to call when the process completes, which updates the status and sets the results. This function will be executed later, after the response was already sent.

Here's that service code:

```
    public CalculationService(CalculationsContext context, ICalculationDriver driver, ILogger<CalculationService> logger)
    {
        this._context = context;
        this._driver = driver;
        this._logger = logger;
    }     

    public Calculation newCalculation(ISet<Format> requestedFormats, string participantId, string caseId, string input)
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var newCalcId = CreateNewCalculationId(caseId, participantId, now);
        var newCalc = new Calculation(newCalcId, caseId, participantId, requestedFormats, now);
        var newInput = new CalculationInput(newCalcId, input);
        _context.Calculations.Add(newCalc);
        _context.CalculationInputs.Add(newInput);
        foreach(Format format in requestedFormats)
        {
            var result = new CalculationResult(newCalcId, format, Status.Needed, null);
            _context.CalculationResults.Add(result);
        }
        
        var calcStartedInfos = _driver.LaunchCalculation(newCalc.Id, input, requestedFormats, (statusUpdate) => {
            //Everything in here is executed later. It is a function passed to the driver which the driver calls to alert this service of status updates
            try
            {
                //Results and Status exist on the same entity, so we might as well grab it once, up here
                var resultEntity = _context.CalculationResults.Find(newCalcId, statusUpdate.Format);

                //If it completed successfully, we need to save the results
                if (statusUpdate.Status == Status.CompletedOk)
                {
                    //Get the results from the driver
                    using Stream resultStream = _driver.RetrieveResults(statusUpdate.CalculationId, statusUpdate.Format);
                    using CryptoStream resultStreamEncoded = new CryptoStream(resultStream, new ToBase64Transform(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
                    using StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resultStreamEncoded);
                    String result = sr.ReadToEnd();

                    //Update the repo with them
                    resultEntity.Result = result;
                }

                //Save the status, whatever it is
                _logger.LogDebug("Updating status for calculation {calcId} format {format} to {status}", statusUpdate.CalculationId, statusUpdate.Format, statusUpdate.Status);
                resultEntity.Status = statusUpdate.Status;
                
                //Finally, persist changes to repo
                _context.SaveChanges();
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                //If we don't eat an exception within this block and we allow it to bubble up, the entire process will crash
                _logger.LogError(e, "An exception occurred while handling a status update from the driver");
                try
                {
                    var resultEntity = _context.CalculationResults.Find(newCalcId, statusUpdate.Format);
                    resultEntity.Status = Status.CompletedErrorsDetected;
                    _context.SaveChanges();

                } catch (Exception e2)
                {
                    _logger.LogError(e2, "Failed to update calculation status after encountering an exception while handling a status update");
                }
            }
        });

        foreach(CalculationStartedInfo startInfo in calcStartedInfos)
        {
            //Each startInfo represents one format, so let's grab the entity for that format
            var resultEntity = _context.CalculationResults.Find(newCalcId, startInfo.Format);
            if (startInfo.Started)
            {
                _logger.LogTrace("Detected Calculation process start successful for calcId: {calculationId} format: {format}", startInfo.CalculationId, startInfo.Format);
                //Set the status to indicate that the calculation has actually started
                resultEntity.Status = Status.ProceedingNormally;
            } else
            {
                _logger.LogError("Detected Calculation process start failed for calcId: {calculationId} format: {format}", startInfo.CalculationId, startInfo.Format);
                //Set the status to indicate that the calculation couldn't even start
                resultEntity.Status = Status.CompletedErrorsDetected;
            }
        }

        _context.SaveChanges();
        return newCalc;
    }
```

The Driver handles communication with an EXE that actually does the calculations. It creates a new Process of that EXE for each Format in the Calculation (that's a slight simplification but it should be good enough) and attaches an exit handler which calls the callback function the service passed in. Here's that code (edited a bit for SO to simplify some irrelevant details):

```
        public IEnumerable<CalculationStartedInfo> LaunchCalculation(string calculationId, string data, IEnumerable<Format> formats, Action<CalculationStatusUpdate> StatusChanged)
        {
            if (StatusChanged == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(StatusChanged), "Status Update function must not be null");
            }

            /* We have to report the initial startup status synchronously because if we report it with a call to StatusChanged
             * it appears to create a race condition against the StatusChanged that is called on Exit */
            List<CalculationStartedInfo> startedReport = new List<CalculationStartedInfo>();

            foreach(Format format in formats)
            {
                //If we use "using" here, the process will be disposed of before the Exited handler is called
                Process p = new Process();
                try
                {
                    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
                    {
                        //Basically we're calling out to an EXE to do the calculations
                    };
                    p.StartInfo = startInfo;
                    p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

                    p.Exited += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
                    {
                        Process endingP = (Process)sender;
                        string calcId = endingP.StartInfo.Environment[FOO_BAR];
                        int actualPid = endingP.Id;
                        int exitCode = endingP.ExitCode;
                        endingP.Dispose();

                        _logger.LogDebug("Process {processId} for calculation id {calculationId} has terminated with code {exitCode}.", actualPid, calcId, exitCode);
                        if (exitCode == 0)
                        {
                            StatusChanged(calculationId, format, Status.CompletedOk);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            StatusChanged(calculationId, format, Status.CompletedErrorsDetected);
                        }

                    };

                    bool isStarted = p.Start();
                    if (isStarted)
                    {
                        _logger.LogDebug("Started {processName} with process id {processId} for calculation id {calculationId}", p.ProcessName, p.Id, calculationId);
                        //Adds a CalculationStartedInfo that reports this Format was successfully started
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _logger.LogError("Failed to start process");
                        //Adds a CalculationStartedInfo that reports this Format was NOT successfully started
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    _logger.LogError(e, "Exception while starting calculation process: " + e.Message);
                    p.Dispose();
                    throw e;
                }

            }

            return startedReport;
        }
```

To reiterate the problem: When the dbContext is used inside the callback, after a response was already sent, an exception is thrown because it has already been disposed.

Answer (score 0):

So I sort of found the answer while I was writing the question, but I figured I'd post it anyway in case it will help someone, or someone else has a better answer to suggest (I could absolutely believe this needs to be refactored).

I found [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37678890/write-to-db-after-controller-has-been-disposed) SO answer from 4 years ago that was promising, but even if I injected a DbContextOptions into my service and tried to do

```
var calcStartedInfos = _driver.LaunchCalculation(newCalc.Id, input, requestedFormats, (statusUpdate) => {
    //Everything in here is executed later. It is a function passed to the driver which the driver calls to alert this service of status updates
    try
    {
        using (var secondContext = new CalculationsContext(_dbContextOptions) {

        ... etc
```

I still couldn't use secondContext. I would get another exception from trying to used a disposed object, except this time the object mentioned was IServiceProvider.

Eventually I found [THIS](https://blog.hildenco.com/2018/12/accessing-entity-framework-context-on.html#:%7E:text=Cannot%20access%20a%20disposed%20object.,context%20in%20a%20using%20statement.) blog post, which led me to this solution:

CalculationService constructor:

```
public CalculationService(CalculationsContext context, IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory, ICalculationDriver driver, ILogger<CalculationService> logger)
    {
        this._context = context;
        this._driver = driver;
        this._logger = logger;

        /*To understand why we need this, see the callback within newCalculation*/
        this._scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
    }
```

CalculationService newCalculation method:

```
    public Calculation newCalculation(ISet<Format> requestedFormats, string participantId, string caseId, string input)
    {
        //yada yada
        
        var calcStartedInfos = _driver.LaunchCalculation(newCalc.Id, input, requestedFormats, (statusUpdate) => {
            //Everything in here is executed later. It is a function passed to the driver which the driver calls to alert this service of status updates
            try
            {
                /* Since this code is executing after the response was already sent, we can't use the original dbContext. It was request-scoped and so is now disposed of.
                   Instead, we are going to ask the singleton "IServiceScopeFactory" for a new scope, and within that scope we'll create a new dbContext */
                using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
                {
                    var secondContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<CalculationsContext>();

                    //Results and Status exist on the same entity, so we might as well grab it once, up here
                    var resultEntity = secondContext.CalculationResults.Find(newCalcId, statusUpdate.Format);

                    //If it completed successfully, we need to save the results
                    if (statusUpdate.Status == Status.CompletedOk)
                    {
                        //Get the results from the driver
                        using Stream resultStream = _driver.RetrieveResults(statusUpdate.CalculationId, statusUpdate.Format);
                        using CryptoStream resultStreamEncoded = new CryptoStream(resultStream, new ToBase64Transform(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
                        using StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resultStreamEncoded);
                        String result = sr.ReadToEnd();

                        //Update the repo with them
                        resultEntity.Result = result;
                    }

                    //Save the status, whatever it is
                    _logger.LogDebug("Updating status for calculation {calcId} format {format} to {status}", statusUpdate.CalculationId, statusUpdate.Format, statusUpdate.Status);
                    resultEntity.Status = statusUpdate.Status;

                    //Finally, persist changes to repo
                    secondContext.SaveChanges();
                }
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                //yada yada
            }
        });

        foreach(CalculationStartedInfo startInfo in calcStartedInfos)
        {
            //yada yada
        }

        _context.SaveChanges();
        return newCalc;
    }
```